# struct doesn't print on new file

Tags: c, linux, codeblocks

Minimal:

```
void read_inputs(studentsT array[],int size,FILE* fp,int *males,int *females,double *malesP,double *femalesP){


int nscan,i,antres,gynekes;
double grades[6],avg,sum;
char name[15],surname[25],gender,termch;
antres = gynekes =0;
*males = 0;
*females = 0;
*malesP = 0;
*femalesP = 0;
while(true){
        nscan = fscanf(fp,"%14[^,], %25[^,], %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %c%c",name,surname,&grades[0],&grades[1],&grades[2],&grades[3],&grades[4],&grades[5],&gender,&termch);
            if (nscan==EOF)break;
            if (nscan != 10 || termch != '\n')
                printf("ERROR");
        if (gender == 'A')
            antres++;
        else
            gynekes++;
    sum = 0;
    sum = sum + grades[0]+grades[1]+grades[2]+grades[3]+grades[4]+grades[5];//makes a sum of grades
    avg = sum /6; //find the avg
for (i=0; i<size;i++){
     if (avg >= 10){ //if the avg is greater than 10, it gives the values it read to a struct
        array[i].avg = avg;
        strcpy(array[i].onoma,name);//copies the name to struct member
        strcpy(array[i].epitheto,surname);//copies the surname to struct member
        array[i].grades[0] = grades[0];//copies the grades
        array[i].grades[1] = grades[1];
        array[i].grades[2] = grades[2];
        array[i].grades[3] = grades[3];
        array[i].grades[4] = grades[4];
        array[i].grades[5] = grades[5];
        strcpy(&array[i].sex,&gender);
        if (gender == 'A')
             ++*males; //counts males with avg more than 10
        else
             ++*females; //counts females with avg more than 10
          }
       }
    }
    *malesP = (*males * 100)/antres; //percentage of males with more than 10 avg
    *femalesP= (*females * 100)/gynekes; //percentage of females with more than 10 avg
```

}

My problem is that it should fill the struct with the information of people with greater than 10 avg, then print it in a new file, thing is that when i print it in main for checking purposes, struct has not any information at all in it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'any information' ?  Zeros?  Garbage?  Try using the debugger.  Set a break point and step through your application, and check all the variables as you go using the Watch Window.

Comment: for readability and ease of understanding, consistently indent the code.  Never use tabs for indenting.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '};  separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement

Comment: regarding these two lines: `while(true){
        nscan = fscanf(fp,"%14[^,], %25[^,], %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %c%c",name,surname,&grades[0],&grades[1],&grades[2],&grades[3],&grades[4],&grades[5],&gender,&termch);`  should be: `while( 10 == ( nscan = fscanf(fp,"%14[^,], %25[^,], %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %c%c",name,surname,&grades[0],&grades[1],&grades[2],&grades[3],&grades[4],&grades[5],&gender,&termch) ) {`   however there also needs to be a check in the `while()` statement that the max number of entries in `array[]` is not exceeded

Comment: for debugging, need the typedef for the `studentT` struct.  So please post that information

Comment: regarding these lines: `       ++*males; //counts males with avg more than 10
            else
                 ++*females;`  there is a precedence problem.  suggest: ``       (*males)++; //counts males with avg more than 10
            else
                 (*females)++;`

Comment: the posted code contains a logic error.  it is looping on i =0...i<size, but only one set of data is available,  suggest init `i` to 0 back in the early code, increment `i` inside the end of the `while()` loop and only save one set of data for each pass through the `while()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

the following code incorporates the comments

does not compile cleanly due to lack of definition of the typedef `studentT`

Will perform the desired operation.

the root of the problem was the setting of every `array[]` entry even when the call to `fscanf()` failed

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_inputs(
    studentsT array[],
    int size,
    FILE* fp,
    int *males,
    int *females,
    double *malesP,
    double *femalesP)
{


    int nscan;
    int i;
    int antres = 0;
    int gynekes = 0;

    double grades[6];
    double avg;
    double sum;

    char name[15];
    char surname[25];
    char gender;
    char termch;

    *males = 0;
    *females = 0;
    *malesP = 0;
    *femalesP = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while( (i < size) && (10 == (nscan = fscanf(fp,
                   "%14[^,], %24[^,], %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %c%c",
                   name,
                   surname,
                   &grades[0],
                   &grades[1],
                   &grades[2],
                   &grades[3],
                   &grades[4],
                   &grades[5],
                   &gender,
                   &termch) ) ) )
    {

        if (gender == 'A')
            antres++;
        else
            gynekes++;


        sum = grades[0]+grades[1]+grades[2]+grades[3]+grades[4]+grades[5];//makes a sum of grades

        avg = sum /6.0; //find the avg

        if (avg >= 10)
        { //if the avg is greater than 10, it gives the values it read to a struct
            array[i].avg = avg;
            strcpy(array[i].onoma,name);//copies the name to struct member
            strcpy(array[i].epitheto,surname);//copies the surname to struct member
            array[i].grades[0] = grades[0];//copies the grades
            array[i].grades[1] = grades[1];
            array[i].grades[2] = grades[2];
            array[i].grades[3] = grades[3];
            array[i].grades[4] = grades[4];
            array[i].grades[5] = grades[5];
            strcpy(&array[i].sex,&gender);

            if (gender == 'A')
                 (*males)++; //counts males with avg more than 10
            else
                 (*females)++; //counts females with avg more than 10
        }
        i++;
    } // end while

    *malesP = ((*males) * 100.0)/antres; //percentage of males with more than 10 avg
    *femalesP= ((*females) * 100.0)/gynekes; //percentage of females with more than 10 average
} // end function: main
```